# Why I Can't send the push notification (Firebase Cloud Messaging) if composed from my own Server

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

we are trying to implement push notification on Android and iOS app, we are using Firebase Cloud Messaging to send push notification to our app.

actually my iOS app can connect to the Firebase Cloud Messaging, If I send the notification through firebase console notification, I can receive the notification in my app
[image]

but if the message is sent through our backend server (PHP), I will not receive the notification in my iOS app, but that message will be arrived in our Android App.

we are still trying to figure out the problem, either it is from client side or from server side. but from the backend server, it send a response error

> Invalid (legacy) Server-key delivered or Sender is not authorized to
>   perform request.

but I also have to ensure that the problem doesn't come from my iOS app. but I also have a doubt, because in my debugging area, it show a message

> FIRMessaging Remote Notifications proxy enabled, will swizzle remote
>   notification receiver handlers. If you'd prefer to manually integrate
>   Firebase Messaging, add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your
>   Info.plist, and set it to NO.

in info.plist i set the value of `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled` to YES

[image]

if I set this to NO as per the message from debugging area like above , then I will not receive the push notification, thats why I set that to YES.

To be honest I completely have no idea what the purpose of that `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled`

what is the function `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled` ?, is that the root cause of the problem on my client side app?

Answer (score 0):

Try use the new api key, not the legacy one. Got the same issue, when I change the key, the push notification is received in iOS client

Answer (score 0):

Make sure both iOS and Android are registered on same Firebase application. In that case, your Server key on Firebase application will be the same for both iOS and Android. I think you are using different keys.

Got my point?